# Programmable Bluetooth transmitter

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-low-energy

As I develop my R&D project I decided to add bluetooth to the mix...  In the first stage I decided to use my own iMac as a transmitter and my iPhone as the receiver, and it worked great...

As I finish this early stage and start to think about field testing, well, I can't carry my 20' iMac around, so I would like to build a low-cost bluetooth transmitter.

My question is: Do I need something like a Arduino/Raspberry or there are "self-contained" transmitters?

Details:

- The transmitter will be plugged into a reliable power source
- The message being transmitted will be fixed and very short (20 bytes max)
- The programming part is: `while(true){ transmitMessage("myId",sleepInterval); }`
- The ideal answer here is something like: "Buy this guy here, download IDE X or Y or Z and here's a Transmitting Hello World Example"

Comment: Beacon?????????

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_lf8_pxg2Q

Comment: You could make your own device very easy. Just buy an atmega328ppu which is used by the arduino uno. A 16MHz crystal. 2x 22pF capacitors. A resistor and button to make a reset possible. And the Bluetooth module of course. You can get a Bluetooth module HC-05 for around $5 from eBay. But for prototyping I'd suggest to buy an Arduino uno when you want to use an atmega328ppu as MCU

Comment: @Handoko wow that sounds great and very cheap! i'm very n00b in this eletrical eng area... i'm a dev... can i contact you via email or something for further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at:

- BLEduino (http://bleduino.cc/)
- BLE mini or Blend Micro (redbearlab.com)
- Possibly RFduino (Be aware thats it is NOT open source or open hardware)

Comment: BLEduino looks dead now?  Forum questions (http://forum.bleduino.cc/t/where-can-i-buy-a-bleduino/143 & http://forum.bleduino.cc/t/where-can-i-buy-more-bleduinos/80) suggest you can't buy them anywhere any more...